# Java: simpler way of cutting off end of string

Tags: java, substring

Everytime I encounter this I ask myself the same question: Isn't there a simpler and less annoying way of cutting a string from the end by X characters.

Let's say I got `"Helly there bla bla"` and - why ever - I need to cut off the last 2 characters, resulting in `"Helly there bla b"`.
I now would do the following:

```
String result = text.substring(0, text.length() - 2);
```

I rather want to do something like:

```
String result = text.cutOffEnd(2);
```

I know there are many String libraries out there, but don't know many of them and I never saw something like that so I hoped someone of you might know better :)

**EDIT:**

**Q:** Why don't you just build your own util method / class?

**A:** I don't want to use an own util method. I don't write a util method for "null or empty" or other trivial things. I go with the opinion that there MUST BE something available already as I would say that tons of people need this kind of function pretty often in their lifetime.
Plus: I work in many different projects and just want to rely on a simple library call like "Strings.nullToEmpty(str)" etc. I just don't build something like that on my own, although it's trivial.

**Q:** why is `text.substring(0, text.length() - 2);` not good enough?

**A:** It's very bulky if you compare it with my desired function. Also, think of that: If you determine the string, it becomes even unhandier:

```
String result = otherClass.getComplicatedCalculatedText(par1, par2).substring(0,
otherClass.getComplicatedCalculatedText(par1, par2).length() - 2);
```

Obviously I'd need to use a local variable, which is so unnecessary at this point... As it could simply be:

```
String result = otherClass.getComplicatedCalculatedText(par1, par2).cutOffEnd(2);
```

Comment: `text.substring(text.length() - 2)` gives you back the **last 2 characters** and **not cut off** the last 2 characters!

Comment: just create your own string util class

Comment: Thanks icza, also realized this just a second ago. Makes the code just more bulky. I edited the question.

Answer (score 5):

By using some string library. I suggest Apache's commons lang.

For your case this is enough.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
String result = StringUtils.removeEnd( "Helly there bla bla", "la");
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through the following code

```
public class OddNumberLoop {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String st1 = "Helly there bla bla";
    String st2 = st1.substring(0, st1.length() - 2);
    System.out.println(st2);

  }
```

}

Good Luck !!!

Comment: I don't understand what you're up to. Explain yourself please. This is what I got and which is bulky and annoying.

Comment: You want to get the st1 string without last two characters, so when we use the substring()  in Java we have to give the start point and end point of the sub-string. In my code, i had gave the first character of the string as the start point and then give the "st1.length() - 2" as the end point. To get the end point, i get the length of the string and deduct 2 . It means that separate the new string from the exist string without last 2 character of the original(st1) string

Comment: This might sound mean, but did you read my question entirely? I know how to do it with substring, but, as stated above in the entry question, this way is bulky and annoying (imo) and it would be so easy to create a beautiful util method - but why doesn't any library got one? That's my question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in utility for this in the starnard library, but how hard is it to write a util method for this yourself?

```
public static String cutOffEnd(String s, int n) {
    return s == null || s.length() <= n ? "" : s.substring(0, s.length() - n);
}
```

A complete solution with checks included:

```
public static String cutOffEnd(String s, int n) {
    if (s == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("s cannot be null!");
    if (n > s.length())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n cannot be greater"
                      + " than the length of string!");

    return s.substring(0, s.length() - n);
}
```

Comment: I would suggest against the use of an utility method like this. It hides a npe in the original call, traded with an empty string; it also adds in the stack; and lowers readability - for such a trivial shortcut of saving one single method parameter

Comment: I don't want to write something like that for myself, I work in many different projects, that's wasted effort if there is a utility library like Strings or StringUtils or any other. Unfortunately I couldn't find sth like that so far :/

Comment: @guido Well this was just for demonstration purposes. A complete solution should also check if `n` is not greater than the length of the `String`.

Comment: @icza yes i understand this answers the question, my comment had probably to go under the OP not here.

Answer (score 0):

- By the way: Often such feature-requests are made to the java-compiler. Usually these features are not Compelling for the Language and *won't be fixed*.
- Why do you like to cut it off? If its for a higher-level-solution then you like to match a pattern or structure. In this case you **anyway shall use a own Util-Method** for parsing.

A realistic Example:

```
String url = "http://www.foo.bar/#abc";
String site = url.substring(0, url.indexOf("#"));
// this shall be extracted into a utils-method 
// anyway like `MyURLParser.cutOfAnchor()`.
```

*Its forbidden to ask for a concrete Library here.*